# Why does this pushViewController not work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pushviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController class, which has a button which triggers this:

```
DetailViewController *viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

Why does the push do nothing? If it matters, the UIViewController is within a UITabBarController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess for this in general is that you haven't yet created a `UINavigationController`. You need to create a `UINavigationController` first, then you can push onto the stack.

You can check for this by using the `navigationController` property  to see whether the current viewController (`self`) is currently in a `UINavigationController`'s hierarchy; if not , the `navigationController` property returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

Because `self.navigationController` is nil? If you didn't create a UINavigationController to manage the contents of the current tab of your UITabBarController then you have nothing to push a new view controller onto.